# Can I broadcast to all WebSocket clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm assuming this isn't possible, but wanted to ask in case it is. If I want to provide a status information web page, I want to use WebSockets to push the data from the server to the browser. But my concerns are the effect a large number of browsers will have on the server. Can I broadcast to all clients rather than send discrete messages to each client?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

WebSockets uses TCP, which is point to point, and provides no broadcast support.

Comment: so even with some scripting language, does broadcasting perform at the same speed as sending message one by one?

Comment: A Websocket framework might make it easy to "Broadcast", but it will be sending discrete messages under the hood. This is why most servers and hosts limit the number of connected clients (Heroku limit used to be 600 clients per Dyno).

Comment: I know  this is old, but I found it today so obviously still visible. There are now plenty of options to "broadcast" to all conected websockets. If you use node server you can use a library like "npm i ws" and loop through each client and send data.

Comment: looping through each client isn't an effective way, say when you have huge number of clients. It would be delayed to the last clients in your loop. So, what can be an alternative?

Comment: **Not to be confused**: we’re talking about the two different “broadcast” in this Q & A. Connectionless broadcast to all unknown nodes within the same network is not possible with TCP-based protocols. In the WebSocket sense, “broadcast” means something different, that is sending to all _connected_ and known clients, which is possible with WebSocket.

Answer (score 34):

Not sure how is your client/server setup, but you can always just keep in the server a collection of all connected clients - and then iterate over each one and send the message.

A simple example using Node's Websocket library:

**Server code**

```
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;

var clients = [];
var socket = new WebSocketServer({
  httpServer: server,
  autoAcceptConnections: false
});

socket.on('request', function(request) {
  var connection = request.accept('any-protocol', request.origin);
  clients.push(connection);

  connection.on('message', function(message) {
    //broadcast the message to all the clients
    clients.forEach(function(client) {
      client.send(message.utf8Data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Since send is just a native copy to socket buffers, this should be very fast, but memory intensive. Most browsers limit the number of concurrent websockets to under 256 for this reason.

Comment: send() will throw exceptions if the client has disconnected, so you'll want to  listen for 'close' event to remove disconnected clients.

Answer (score 25):

As noted in other answers, WebSockets don't support multicast, but it looks like the 'ws' module maintains a list of connected clients for you, so it's pretty easy to iterate through them. From [the docs](https://github.com/websockets/ws):

```
const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });

wss.broadcast = function(data) {
  wss.clients.forEach(client => client.send(data));
};
```

Comment: But lest see there are 10000 users connected do I need to loop them all? Its time-consuming. Is there any technique to broadcast to some users

Comment: @mandaputtra _"WebSockets don't support multicast"_ - what more info do you need?

Comment: @mandaputtra There are other network protocols that allow broadcasting.  E.g. "multicast addressing" (google it) let's you do broadcasting at OSI levels 2 or 3.  But websockets are based on HTTP over TCP, which inherently does not support broadcasting.  Thus, to send to a subset or all clients you need to iterate through all of the connected clients.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to broadcast messages to multiple clients.

In Java,

```
  @OnMessage
  public void onMessage(String m, Session s) throws IOException {
  for (Session session : s.getOpenSessions()) {
    session.getBasicRemote().sendText(m);
   }
}
```

and here it is explained.
https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/optimized_websocket_broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and there are many socket servers out there written in various scripting languages that are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the server-side really. Here's an example of how it's done using [Tomcat7](http://tomcat.apache.org/):

[Tomcat 7 Chat Websockets Servlet Example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/websocket/chat/ChatWebSocketServlet.java)

and an explanation of the how it's constructed [here](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2012/05/01/how-apache-tomcat-implemented-websocket).

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft.Web.WebSockets namespace has a WebSocketCollection with Broadcast capability. Look for the assembly in Nuget. The name is Microsoft.WebSockets.