# Run a specific function globally using Node,js

Tags: html, node.js

I want to run a function globally using Node.js, but the problem is I don't know how to do that.

If your wondering what I mean, I want to run a function on all web servers available for my website.

Let's say I want to run `alert()`. When a user presses a button on the webpage, is there any way to cast this throughout all running versions of the webpage?

Comment: No. It sounds like you want to set up websockets or similar. You're not asking to run a function on the web *server*, you're asking for something to happen on the *client* ("web browser").

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What you're describing is a broadcast from one client to all other clients. You can complete this with a stateful full-duplex line of communication like [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155528/can-i-broadcast-to-all-websocket-clients) that shows how a back-end service could be coded to broadcast a message to all connected clients. You have a layer of complexity here with multiple service instances, but [AWS SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) may help.